# Java Apache POI Opening file?

Tags: java, excel, file-io, apache-poi

I have a Java program that edits an existing excel file and saves it as a new file. However, I would also like the program to automatically open the newly created file upon ending. Is there an apache poi command that lets me do this?

Comment: have you written any snippet to open the file ?? share it please .

Comment: By _"automatically open the newly created file upon ending"_ do you mean you want to launch Excel to open the newly created file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have not Provided Code , I m using the Example of **[ViralPatel Tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/)**

**Lets Create Excel File First**

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");

    Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
    data.put("1", new Object[] { "Emp No.", "Name", "Salary" });
    data.put("2", new Object[] { 1d, "John", 1500000d });
    data.put("3", new Object[] { 2d, "Sam", 800000d });
    data.put("4", new Object[] { 3d, "Dean", 700000d });

    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (obj instanceof Date)
                cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Boolean)
                cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Double)
                cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
        }
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\new.xls"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

        /** Opening Excel File From Java **/

        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:\\new.xls"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output

[image]

Solution : Put this code with Try/Catch Block after You have created Excel with correct Location, It will be opened Automatically

> **Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:\new.xls"));**

Else u can invoke this as well

Try to use Desktop.open() instead of Desktop.edit() :

```
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.open(new File("D:\\new.xls"));
```

If Desktop.open() is not available then the Windows file association can be used :

```
 Process p =    Runtime.getRuntime()    .exec("rundll32
 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + "D:\\new.xls");
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) and [Desktop JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know wheter POI is providing such methods or not. However you can do this using simple java method that uses the command prompt and open the desired file using `start` command.

```
public static void openExcelFile(){
    try{    
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+FilePath);
    }catch(IOException  e){  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
```

**NOTE: The space after `start` is mandatory. Don't forget it**

Comment: My inner Captain Obvious wants to say that this will only work on Windows machines. As an improvement, the command may be passed as an argument; upvoted!