# Open remote excel file in java

Tags: java, excel, file-io, apache-poi

I have tried snippet given in the below thread,it works perfectly on the local system where I have developed.

It is an web application ,on click of the button, excel file is generated and at the same time opened.

I am able to open excel sheet when I access the web application link from local system but when I access the application from remote system then It generates the file on my local system but doesn't open the excel file on that remote system.

[Java Apache POI Opening file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184041/java-apache-poi-opening-file)

Do I need to share the drive?

Edit : 
Used below snippet to directly open the excel

```
Process p =    Runtime.getRuntime()    .exec("rundll32
 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + "D:\\new.xls");
```

Comment: Well, the file will need to be accessible by Excel on the local system (either as a local drive or shared over the network). What have you done to facilitate this?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos:File is accessible on local system.and if I share the drive then would i be able to open it on remote system??

Comment: If you just want to show it using Excel as a viewer, no.

Comment: If you're building a web based system, then surely you should be getting the web browser to download the generated excel file, no?

Comment: @Gagravarr No , Directly opening the excel sheet using snippet given in question section.

Comment: Why are you doing it that way though? Given they're already accessing your web application, why not send them the file and have their web browser prompt them to open excel to view it?